# How to migrate the ActiveMQ "Classic" with Spring 5 to Spring 6?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm implementing JMS using ActiveMQ "Classic" and Spring 5 to handle requests/responses between distributed components in the application. (Requests send from a Web component to an ActiveMQ broker. There is a business component that listens and handles the requests from the broker, then sends responses to correlation requests)

For technical reasons (vulnerability and keeping the stuff up to date), we need to migrate to Spring 6. However, most of the JMS API was deprecated and removed in Spring 6, especially the package `org.springframework.jms.remoting.*`

I do some research to try migrating the JMS part, but I do not find out one.

Could you please give me suggestions, solutions, or reference resources to solve this migration?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ 5.18.1 has a client jar to support jakarta (used by Spring 6)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-client-jakarta</artifactId>
  <version>5.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```